# Youtube.Search.list(..).getItems return a String? how to easily transform or filter items?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I call YouTube Data API and get this error:

`searchResults.getItems().map(item => item.id.videoId)};`

`searchResults.getItems(...).map is not a function`

`items` are a String? how can I easily transform or filter `items`?

[image]

Comment: Please be kind to not post source code embedded within images. Indeed is easier for the poster to just capture his/her screen, but for the readers of that post is really painful working on a screenshot (e.g. one cannot easily do copy-paste on that source code). Not to mention that this goes against basic SO posting guideline rules.

Comment: Thanks! but this time copy-pasting my code is not really related. I will add the code next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
var a = [0], b = [1], c = a + b;
console.log(typeof(c));
```

produces `string` on `console`. This one:

```
var a = {};
console.log(String(a.map));
a.map();
```

produces the line:

```
undefined
```

along with the error message:

```
TypeError: a.map is not a function
```

The same things happen when having `var a = "";` instead.

You should replace:

```
searchResults['items'] =
searchResults['items'] + nextPage['items'];
```

with:

```
searchResults['items'] =
searchResults['items'].concat(nextPage['items']);
```

assuming that both `searchResults['items']` and `nextPage['items']` are arrays.